# MySQL Master-Master Replication Table Row COUNT() Inconsistency

Tags: mysql, replication

I have two MySQL servers replicating to each other in a Master-Master typology.

This has been working fine for several months now.

Recently I've noticed some drift in one Master. There is a row COUNT(*) inconsistency on one table only in the database. The other tables in the database return the same row COUNT(*) on both Masters.

This table has approx. 120,000 rows and seems to be short by about ~80 rows after replicating from Master #1 (M1) to Master #2 (M2).

I have tried the following:

- Duplicate table T1 on M1 to create T2. Then run count after T2 has replicated from M1 to M2. The count on M1 is higher than on M2.
- Duplicating table T2 on M1 to create T3. Then run count after T3 has replicated from M1 to M2. The count is again short. The count on M1 is higher than on M2.
- Duplicating table T3 **on M2** to create T4. Then run count after T4 has replicated from M2 to M1. The count on M1 is higher than on M2.

Any clues as to why Master #1 (M1) appears to be able to count more rows in the same table each time?

Comment: What is your `BINLOG_FORMAT` set to?  I am guessing `MIXED` or `STATEMENT`.  What server versions?  InnoDB or MyISAM?  Also, this should go without asking, but does this table have a primary key?